# Changing the Index of a StackLayout from another object

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a StackLayout in my app and I am trying to change it's current index from the press of a button like this:

```
ApplicationWindow 

{
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test")

     StackLayout 
     {
        id: mainStack

        WelcomePage // Custom qml page with button (userLoginMouseArea)
        {
            id: welcomeId
            mainStack.currentIndex: userLoginMouseArea.pressed ? 1 : 0
        }

        Page
        {
            // switch to this page if button is pressed
        }
     }
}
```

I am getting an error in Qt Creator

```
Invalid property name mainStack (M16)
```

and when I try to build I get a "non-existent property mainStack error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mainStack.currentIndex` is not a property of `WelcomePage` so it is not correct to make the connection in that place, you have to do it in `StackLayout`:

```
StackLayout
{
    id: mainStack

    currentIndex: welcomeId.userLoginMouseArea.pressed ? 1 : 0

    WelcomePage
    {
        id: welcomeId
    }
    Page
    {

    }
}
```

Although I do not think that in your case is the solution since you have made a binding between the `pressed` button and the `currentIndex` so if you stop pressing the button it will show `WelcomePage` again, if you wish to only change the page you could pass the clicked signal :

**WelcomePage.qml**

```
Page {
    id: pg
    signal clicked()
    MouseArea{
        id: ma
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: pg.clicked()
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
StackLayout
{
    id: mainStack
    anchors.fill: parent

    WelcomePage
    {
        id: welcomeId
        onClicked:  mainStack.currentIndex = 1
    }
    Page
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Even though your first answer seemed to work fine I understand what your concern was (I was getting a looping warning). I changed the code to use your new snippet and everything is working fine now without any warnings. Thanks again.